# How to create a CRON task to execute a javascript file that writes into another file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-app-engine, cron, gcloud

I have a local JS environment where I have 2 files, app.js and users.json. When I run the command “node app.js” on the CLI it updates the users.json within the same local environment.
I am new to this, so I would like to know how to automate this process to run every 5 min on a webserver where the app.js execution(“node app.js”) updates the users.json file. I would appreciate if someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: Are you asking about how to do it **locally** or inside **App Engine**?. The environments are different and the solution might not apply both cases. Also, it is in the context of GAE standard or flexible?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using cpanel, you may use CronJob tab to achive this task, you can set your execution time of that file in the cronjob tab and set the location of the file.